# Ubuntu 16.04, connects to wifi, no internet

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, internet

I am able to connect to my home wifi but I don't get access to internet and I'm not able to ping anything. Not even the router. I've tried a couple of other wifi networks and they work just fine, and if I connect with a cable at home it also works.

I have a Hitron CVE-30360 router

I've set the IPv6 setting to "ignore", and tried assigning different IPs manually.

lshw suggested that I have a generic driver for my wireless card, so I tried installing the appropriate driver from [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html), however output from lshw didn't change at all. Did I not manage to install the driver properly?

Output from sudo lshw -class *network:

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 35
   serial: 00:24:d7:b2:db:10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=9.176.4.1 build 15835 ip=192.168.0.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:28 memory:d2400000-d2401fff
```

Output from ifconfig

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:cc:5d:b7:f3  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:106872 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:72481 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:128170557 (128.1 MB)  TX bytes:8936682 (8.9 MB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:d2500000-d2520000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:12349 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:12349 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:1086407 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1086407 (1.0 MB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:d7:b2:db:10  
      inet addr:192.168.0.4  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::224:d7ff:feb2:db10/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1545 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:520108 (520.1 KB)  TX bytes:14457 (14.4 KB)
```

Output from route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```